# Javascript regex to filter hexadecimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check, if the string is valid hexadecimal number in 0x3f (for example) format.

```
var strRegex="0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+";
var re = new RegExp(strRegex);
if (!re.test(theAddress) {.... error alert stuff... }
```

As I have it now, it accept stuff like 0x3q and so on.

What regex expression should I use instead?

Comment: Missing a start and end check

Answer (score 2):

Put anchors arround the regex:

```
var strRegex = "^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+$";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put word boundaries `\b` around the pattern:

```
var re = new RegExp("\b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b");
```

If you miss them the string `0x3q` would match too since it contains `0x3` which would match the pattern. Using `\b` it would only match `0x3` if it is surrounded either by a space, tab the begin or the end of the string `,`, `;` etc.

Others suggested to use the `^` and `$` anchors but this will only work if the string contains exactly one hexadecimal value. The solution with word boundaries matches also strings which contain one (or more) hex values.

Comment: word boundaries are underappreciated